# What is the best way to convert an array of bytes Java code to python?

Tags: python, java, python-3.x, byte

I have tried several ways to convert this Java instruction to python, but I always get some error or wrong outputs. What is the correct way to do it?

`String x = new String(new byte[]{(byte) 23353, (byte) 333, (byte) 614537057});`
(x is equal to string "9Ma")

I tried `x = bytes([23353, 5682, 10310]).decode('utf-8')`
But the result is: ValueError: byte must be in range(0, 256)

Comment: That Java code makes very little sense. It relies on a narrowing primitive conversion to convert ints to bytes. Your actual byte values are 57, 77 and 97.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, you can't pass values larger than `255` to the `bytes()` function.
However, you can pass the `%256` value:

```
byte_values = [23353, 333, 614537057]
x = "".join(chr(value % 256) for value in byte_values)
print(x)
```

The above code prints `9Ma` on my side.

However, I'd suggest you to functionally verify the sense of what your Java code is doing because it is shortcutting the above conversion from `int` to `byte` instead of directly producing the correct bytes.

Answer (score -1):

Because a Byte is 8 bit long, which adds up to a maximum of 256 in decimal. In Java it will take the first Byte of your number and convert it to ascii.

Comment: Not the first byte, but the last byte. I.e. the 8 lowest order bits.